# Check for empty of null in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I had a bug that turned out to be because I forgot to check for null values. I added the check, but would like if it could be written more concise.

```
<ListItem onClick={!pattern.capped && !pattern.hasInlineRef ? search(pattern.dbValue, pattern.dbValue === "" || pattern.dbValue === null) : undefined}>
```

Can this check for empty or null be shortened?

```
search(pattern.dbValue, pattern.dbValue === "" || pattern.dbValue === null)
```

It's written in Typescript, but I guess the curly braces make it JavaScript.

Comment: "*It's written in Typescript, but I guess the curly braces make it JavaScript.*" all TypeScript compiles to JavaScript. At runtime, you only have JS running.

Comment: At least extract the `dbValue` property first, I think. If its only falsey values are the empty string and null, just call `Boolean` on it in the second argument

Comment: you can write some util function for that and use the function to get rid of long code. One more additional thing is `undefined` check

Answer (score 2):

First, you can create an util function to check null, empty or undefined:

```
export function isNullOrEmpty(value) {
    return (value === null || value === undefined || value === "") ? true : false 
}
```

Or, you can fast test with falsy and truthy:

```
search(pattern.dbValue, !pattern.dbValue)
```

**List of falsy values in JavaScript: [MDN Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)**

1. false
2. null
3. undefined
4. 0
5. NaN
6. ''
7. document.all

Comment: yup, it is a good practice to isolate a function one of few reasons is, easy testing.

Comment: Equality checks are already truthy/falsy, just `return value === null || value === undefined || value === "";`, or because all those values *are* [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values, just double-bang it, `return !!value;`. The only reason I can see for explicit checks is *if* 0 or `NaN` needed to be treated differently.

Comment: `!value` would be enough, yes.

Comment: Edit went in same time as my comment. :)

Comment: @DrewReese but then that would also catch `0` which might be undesirable.

Comment: @VLAZ see the last sentence of my comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an helper function in a separate folder and pull out this function into the files where you need to check for null, undefined, empty string or an empty object.You can write something like this:

```
export default value =>
value === undefined ||
value === null ||
(typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
(typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0);
```

Hope this helps